# Page_ClientValidate('') can i do this at a control level

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, customvalidator

Does anyone know the way i can do similar to `Page_ClientValidate` in a way that not all of the controls on the page will be validated against? i.e. how i can just validate a particular custom validator is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a ValidationGroup to group your controls. Then specify that string to the Page_ClientValidate function like so

```
<asp:TextBox id="text" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vld1" />
<asp:CheckBox id="check" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vld2" />

Page_ClientValidate('vld1');
```